# How can I disable the Include Bitcode during an azure devops pipeline?

Tags: ios, azure-pipelines, browserstack

I Have an Azure Devops pipeline setup to build an ios app and then upload the .ipa file to browserstack for testing.

This is the task I'm using in the pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops

This produces a .ipa file, however the include bitcode option appears to be enabled by default and this is the browserstack error that is returned below :

{"error":"[BROWSERSTACK_BITCODE_ENABLED_APP_UPLOAD_ERROR] Currently, we do not support iOS apps built with App Store distribution profile and Include bitcode for iOS content check enabled. To fix this issue, we recommend uploading Ad hoc, Enterprise or Development profiles while exporting the IPA of your iOS app. If you have any concerns please reach out to support."}

I have tried setting the exportMethod to ad-hoc, Development and Enterprise during the Task.

Is there a way to disable the include bitcode during the pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the target settings. Click the `Build Settings`, and type `bitcode` in the search bar, then disable it.
[image]